# GWT + eclipse, which files are part of my source?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, build

i created a GWT project in eclipse, and it's time to put some code back into source control. i'm not sure at this point which files are generated and can be left out of source control,

a. under war/myapp/gwt/... i see many, many files related to the standard GWT themes.

b. under war/myapp,

```
-rw-r--r--  1 10102022  1602597546   1876 Jan 24 16:41 0182DE3CC529E42DA72BBD969A44841E.gwt.rpc
-rw-r--r--  1 10102022  1602597546   1456 Jan 24 14:09 4F701266A6E52E1E409583EA9AEC39E2.gwt.rpc
-rw-r--r--  1 10102022  1602597546   1876 Jan 25 08:38 D98FD8FE56B70659E9608109BCF8B3C1.gwt.rpc
-rw-r--r--  1 10102022  1602597546     43 Dec 16 16:01 clear.cache.gif
drwxr-xr-x  6 10102022  1602597546    204 Jan 25 08:26 gwt
-rw-r--r--  1 10102022  1602597546  11289 Dec 17 01:33 hosted.html
-rw-r--r--  1 10102022  1602597546   5232 Jan 25 08:31 photodrop_web_gwt.nocache.js
```

normally i'd just rely on eclipse build > clean to get rid of the build time artifacts. however, i did that, and i still see WEB-INF/classes full of class files, so i know that clean isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"war/myapp" is by default GWT's output directory. So as long as you haven't saved any files there manually (you shouldn't), you can delete that directory completely.

As always, make a backup first...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using source control for GWT + GAE, and this ignore file has been working great:

```
syntax: regexp
^war/myapp$
syntax: regexp
^war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/datastore-indexes-auto\.xml$
syntax: regexp
^war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db\.bin
```